# Batch-replace a bunch of strings in a text file with Emacs

Tags: emacs

To replace all the occurrences of 'foo' in a text file with some other string, the usual Emacs command is `M-x replace-string`.

Off late, I have had to replace several such strings in my text files. Doing 
`M-x replace-string`  for every expression I want to replace is tiring. Is there any Emacs command to 'batch replace' a bunch of strings with their alternatives?

This might look something like,

`M-x batch-replace-strings RET foo1, foo2, foo3, RET bar1, bar2, bar3 RET`
where RET stands for hitting the return key.

So now foo1 has been replaced with bar1, foo2 with bar2 and foo3 with bar3.

Comment: The solution of [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588277/how-can-i-swap-or-replace-multiple-strings-in-code-at-the-same-time) is applicable, provided the input is rearranged slightly as follows: M-x parallel-replace RET foo1 bar1 foo2 bar2 foo3 bar3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code does what you want, prompting for the string pairs pair-by-pair:

```
(defun batch-replace-strings (replacement-alist)
  "Prompt user for pairs of strings to search/replace, then do so in the current buffer"
  (interactive (list (batch-replace-strings-prompt)))
  (dolist (pair replacement-alist)
    (save-excursion
      (replace-string (car pair) (cdr pair)))))

(defun batch-replace-strings-prompt ()
  "prompt for string pairs and return as an association list"
  (let (from-string
        ret-alist)
    (while (not (string-equal "" (setq from-string (read-string "String to search (RET to stop): "))))
      (setq ret-alist
            (cons (cons from-string (read-string (format "Replace %s with: " from-string)))
                  ret-alist)))
    ret-alist))
```