# How to exchange words in emacs(by replace them with each other one)

Tags: emacs

Say I have some text like:

```
First one is good, so I used first one.Second one is bad, so I drop it.
```

I want to switch the 'first' and 'second',and like replace-string,leave the capital to the same case as original word.

Is there any built-in functions to handle this situations?

Edit:
Let me explain the problem further.If I use usual replace-string twice,will some times cause unwanted results.In the example above, If using replace-string first RET second RET, then replace-string second RET first RET,it will out put: First one is good. so I used first one.First one is bad, so I drop it. It also a problem in some case like "clientFolder=>serverFolder and server=> client"

Comment: yes, first you hit ctrl+c, then type vi <filename>, then you are good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a great trick courtesy of Mickey's Mastering Emacs blog (see http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/01/25/evaluating-lisp-forms-regular-expressions/ under the heading "Swapping Elements")

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `\(first\)\|second` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\,(if \1 "second" "first")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

**Edit:** and here's an elisp version of that:

```el
(defun my-swap-text (a b)
  "Swap two pieces of text wherever they appear, using `query-replace-regexp'."
  (interactive "sSwap: \nswith: ")
  (let ((use-region (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)))
    (query-replace-regexp
     (rx (or (group (eval a)) (eval b)))
     (quote (replace-eval-replacement replace-quote (if (match-string 1) b a)))
     nil
     (when use-region (region-beginning))
     (when use-region (region-end)))))
```

Comment: Imma let you finish but @huaiyuan already wrote the most gangsta command of all time to solve this.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty cool :)

Answer (score 4):

@huaiyuan answered the same question here:

[How can I swap or replace multiple strings in code at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588277/how-can-i-swap-or-replace-multiple-strings-in-code-at-the-same-time)

His code allows you to enter arbitrary list of pairs to do parallel replacement.

Incidently, if you want to read some cool lisp code, click on @huaiyuan and read his answers.

Answer (score -1):

did you google search this at all?

http://kb.iu.edu/data/abdp.html

Comment: Unconditional search and replace twice will created unwanted result,while Queried search and replace is not convenient enough.

Comment: so an unconditional search that replaces the first text with some placeholder like "BLAHBLAHBLAH", then replace the second text with the first, then replace "BLAHBLAHBLAH" with the second wouldn't work?

Comment: well that's what I'm doing now.And it's really annoying.So if there is no built-in functions,I may just write one.

Comment: Actually, this is also a good usecase for regular expressions. M-x replace-regexp in Emacs.

Comment: As for annoying operations, you can record a macro. Just press F3, do your annoying operations, press F4 to save, and when you press F4 again, Emacs will repeat the recorded keystrokes for you. Read more about Emacs macros in help.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky That's good,I didnt know key macros support prompting.Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't replacing with placeholders be considered unsafe? Who knows what strange words might lurk in a text!